# Live Chat API: Any guarantee of initial /Messages entry?

Tags: rest-api, liveagent

When long-polling the Live Chat API /Messages endpoint, the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_Messages.htm) indicate that all messages sent between agent/chat visitor are returned in order, from a [list of possible Message types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_Messages_responses_overview.htm).  After looking at the possible message types, it seems reasonable to assume that the first message should always be either `ChatRequestFail` or `ChatRequestSuccess`, and empirical testing matches that expectation, but I cannot find any documentation of that assertion.  Are there edge cases that would cause another Message type to come first?  Is there any additional documentation I should be referring to?